# SwiftUI Previews Multitasking Options

Tags: ios, swiftui, ipad, swiftui-previews

Is it possible to test the different multitasking options like Side by Side and Slide Over views for iPad in SwiftUI Previews?

Example:
View()..previewDevice("device") can be used to launch the preview on a particular device
or
View().previewInterfaceOrientation(.landscapeLeft) can be used to launch the preview in a particular orientation

but how to launch the view preview as it would be shown in a slide over view when multitasking on an iPad.